# Как для C# сгенерить модели из WADL?

Tags: c#, rest

Есть рест веб сервис, который выдает WADL, каким генератором можно нагенерить C# код для моделей респонсов/реквестов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно попробовать вот этой утилитой сгенерировать

[WADL - RESTful WCF Services Client Code Generation Utility](https://wadl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Похоже какого-то генератора, который активно поддерживался для .Net нет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть в системе три программы для генерации классов. Это disco.exe (Программа для обнаружения URL-адресов XML-веб-служб, расположенных на веб-сервере,
и сохранения связанных с этой XML-веб-службой документов на локальном диске.
Файлы results.discomap, WDSL и XSD, создаваемые этим средством, можно
 использовать с программой wsdl.exe для создания клиентов веб-служб и абстрактных серверов веб-служб с помощью ASP.NET.), wsdl.exe (Программа для создания кода для клиентов XML-веб-службы и XML-веб-служб,
использующих ASP.NET из файлов контракта WSDL, схемы XSD и обнаруженные
документы discomap. Это средство можно использовать совместно с программой disco.exe.) и xsd.exe (Программа для создания файлов схем или классов из заданного источника.). Находятся они в папке "Microsoft SDKs\Windows\версия\bin\" (у меня они в папке "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools"). Запускаются из командной строки. Может они Вам помогут? Я лично, правда работал только с xsd.exe. Отлично генерило, очень редко требовалась ручная корректиовка.

Comment: С wsdl понятно, но с wadl не работает.

Comment: Жаль, думал поможет...